# How to update (assign new values) to R data frames stored in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, assign

```
# sample data
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(1)
v1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(4,3)
v2 = rep("",4)
df1 = data.frame(v1, v2)

set.seed(2)
v1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(4,3)
v2 = rep("",4)
df2 = data.frame(v1, v2)

df.list = list(df1,df2)
df.list

[[1]]
   v1 v2
1 GNZ   
2 uCt   
3 wed   
4 3CA   

[[2]]
   v1 v2
1 BhZ   
2 Aww   
3 8pT   
4 YYE
```

I want to assign a substring of v1 to v2 for every row of every data frame in a vectorised manner, e.g., v2 = the third character of v1, to get this:

```
> df.list
[[1]]
   v1 v2
1 GNZ  Z
2 uCt  t
3 wed  d
4 3CA  A

[[2]]
   v1 v2
1 BhZ  Z
2 Aww  w
3 8pT  T
4 YYE  E
```

I know this for-loop works

```
for (df in 1:2){
    df.list[[df]]$v2 = substr(df.list[[df]]$v1, 3, 3)
}
df.list
```

I know I could use `rbind.fill(df.list)` and then set `$v2 = substr($v1, 3, 3)`

I know I could substring before storing the data frame in the list, but I'd rather substring all at once.

I'd like to keep the data in a list b/c the list is indexed by a string that will be used in other code. The rbind.fill does not keep the index / rowname.

I know this does NOT work

```
sapply(df.list, "[[", "v2") <- sapply(df.list, function(x) substr(x$v1, 3,3))
```

Even though the right side identifies the correct substrings. I realize the sapply on the left side is an output function and does not point to the  target. But this conveys the idea of what I'm trying to do.

This also generates the substring `sapply(df.list, function(x) {x$v2 <- substr(x$v1,3,3)})` but the assignment does not get made.

So how do I point to the same column of every structurally equivalent data frame stored in a list to make the assignment in a vectorized manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lapply` lets you apply functions easily over each element in a list.
Heres a solution using `lapply` and `dplyr`'s `mutate` function.

```
lapply(df.list, function(df) dplyr::mutate(df, v2=substr(v1,3,3)))
```

Alternate solutions using base R.

```
lapply(df.list, function(df) data.frame(v1=df$v1, v2=substr(df$v1,3,3)))

lapply(df.list, function(df) {
  df$v2 <- substr(df$v1,3,3)
  return(df)
})
```

Comment: You could also use `transform` in base R as an analogy to `dplyr::mutate` - `lapply(df.list, transform, v2=substr(v1,3,3) )`

Comment: @thelatemailI like the idea but the warning in the transform() documentation applies to my case

Comment: @Adam Spannbauer the 3rd option, which you, thankfully, added in a later edit, is the best one for my real world situation since my df.list has additional columns.  It's very similar to one of my tries, though I missed the return(). Very good alternatives that teach.  I found mutate_all, though the documentation indicates that it will be deprecated.