# Change data type of all columns in list of data frames before using `bind_rows()`

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a list of data frames, e.g. from the following code:

```
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accidents_and_disasters_by_death_toll" %>% 
    rvest::read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes(css = 'table[class="wikitable sortable"]') %>% 
    html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

I would now like to combine the dataframes into one, e.g. with `dplyr::bind_rows()` but get the `Error: Can't combine` ..1$Deaths`<integer> and`..5$Deaths `<character>.` (the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377370/bind-rows-of-different-data-types) doesn't do the trick).

So I need to convert the data types before using row binding. I would like to use this inside a pipe (a tidyverse solution would be ideal) and not loop through the data frames due to the structure of the remaining project but instead use something vectorized like `lapply(., function(x) {lapply(x %>% mutate_all, as.character)})` (which doesn't work) to convert all values to `character`.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update (assign new values) to R data frames stored in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282845/how-to-update-assign-new-values-to-r-data-frames-stored-in-a-list)

Comment: `tables <-  lapply(tables, function(df) dplyr::mutate(df, Deaths = suppressWarnings(as.integer(Deaths))))`   ; verify with `lapply(tables, function(x) class(x$Deaths)) %>% unique()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change all the column classes to characters and bind them together with `map_df`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accidents_and_disasters_by_death_toll" %>% 
  rvest::read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(css = 'table[class="wikitable sortable"]') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  map_df(~.x %>% mutate(across(.fns = as.character)))

 # Deaths Date    Attraction               `Amusement park`  Location        Incident Injuries
 #  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>                    <chr>             <chr>           <chr>    <chr>   
 #1 28     14 Feb… Transvaal Park (entire … Transvaal Park    Yasenevo, Mosc… NA       NA      
 #2 15     27 Jun… Formosa Fun Coast music… Formosa Fun Coast Bali, New Taip… NA       NA      
 #3 8      11 May… Haunted Castle; a fire … Six Flags Great … Jackson Townsh… NA       NA      
 #4 7      9 June… Ghost Train; a fire at … Luna Park Sydney  Sydney, Austra… NA       NA      
 #5 7      14 Aug… Skylab; a crane collide… Hamburger Dom     Hamburg, (Germ… NA       NA      
# 6 6      13 Aug… Virginia Reel; a fire a… Palisades Amusem… Cliffside Park… NA       NA      
# 7 6      29 Jun… Eco-Adventure Valley Sp… OCT East          Yantian Distri… NA       NA      
# 8 5      30 May… Big Dipper; the roller … Battersea Park    Battersea, Lon… NA       NA      
# 9 5      23 Jun… Kuzuluk Aquapark swimmi… Kuzuluk Aquapark  Akyazi, Turkey… NA       NA      
#10 4      24 Jul… Big Dipper; a bolt came… Krug Park         Omaha, Nebrask… NA       NA      
# … with 1,895 more rows
```